# Index Match 2 criteria in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro I'm trying to create to map a bunch of old values to new values.  At one point I need to do a match on 2 columns and get the value from a third column.  In normal excel I would run the formula below, but as it is a Formula Array (have to CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to run) I'm not quite sure how to get this to work in VBA

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(1,(E2=$A:$A)*(F2=$B:$B),0))
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
Cell.FormulaArray()
```

It should work with normal notation, although it is intended for R1C1

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with it or quite sure how the syntax should work exactly?



    var3 = cell.FormulaArray(WorksheetFunction.Index(wsM.Range("$D:$D"), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (wsM.Range("$A:$A") = tagN) * (wsM.Range("$B:$B") = tagS), 0)))

Comment: Also doesnt work: var3.FormulaArray = WorksheetFunction.Index(wsM.Range("$D:$D"), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (wsM.Range("$A:$A") = tagN) * (wsM.Range("$B:$B") = tagS), 0))

Comment: Just use the formula exactly as you would enter it in a cell. So if you would want to insert it in A1,  use Range("A1"). FormulaArray = "=INDEX(..."

Comment: It just seems to be returning 0.  Not sure if its because Im not selecting the worksheet properly?  Added the wsM.Activate to ensure it was on the correct sheet but doesnt seem to be helping.  Sorry, my vb is a bit rudimentary:

wsM.Activate
                    wsI.Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & "$D:$D ,MATCH(1,(" & tagN & "=$A:$A)*(" & tagS & "=$B:$B),0))"
                    wsS.Activate

Comment: Not sure what your problem might be, maybe "wsl" refers to a different worksheet? But then, the formula would appear there.

Comment: I switched the output to the same sheet, and now I get #NA with the following formula.  Guessing I need the quotes around my variables (tagN & tagS, show as Clinical Diagnostics Selections & Quality Control), but I don't seem to be able to escape them: =INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(1,(Clinical Diagnostics Selections=$A:$A)*(Quality Control=$B:$B),0))  

And then: Range("E1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & "$D:$D ,MATCH(1,(" & tagN & "=$A:$A)*(" & tagS & "=$B:$B),0))"

Comment: Just just double double quotes (""), that creates a single " in the output. So for your formula, it would read """ & var & """

Comment: Thanks, got there in the end!  Code: Range("E1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & "$D:$D ,MATCH(1,(""" & tagN & """=$A:$A)*(""" & tagS & """=$B:$B),0))"

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially three ways to evaluate an array formula to a result within VBA.

The first is 'square bracket' evaluation. This processes a formula just as if it is on the worksheet.

```
Dim result As Variant
result = [INDEX('Sheet1'!D:D,MATCH(1,(E2='Sheet1'!A:A)*(F2='Sheet1'!B:B),0))]
Debug.Print result
```

Care must be given to explicitly show worksheet parentage. In the above, the full columns have been given a parent worksheet but the individual cells have not. The individual cells will default to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) which may or may not even be in the same workbook. Define all cell references explicitly!

The second method is with [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx). This allows more freedom with the formulas using string construction.

```
Dim result As Variant, wsn As String
wsn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Name
result = Application.Evaluate("INDEX('" & wsn & "'!D:D, " & _
             "MATCH(1, (E2='" & wsn & "'!A:A)*(F2='" & wsn & "'!B:B),0))")
Debug.Print result
```

Again, only the full column references have been given parent worksheet references. This should be fixed before run-time use. This method is better for array formulas because you can use string construction to cut the full column references down to the rows in the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

As mentioned, the third method involves writing the formula to a worksheet cell using the [Range.FormulaArray property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx) and retrieving the answer from the cell.

Comment: Thanks, this is very thorough! :)